# The tablix 'Tablix1' is invalid. The value for the DataSetName Property is missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

For some weird reason i can not run my report, when i try to preview i get this error:

[image]

Here is how my tablix property looks like:

[image]

Any idea what to do? The current .rdl was copied from another one. I changed the newly copied .rdl values to match my needs. I always do that and works perfect, instead of creating the design from scratch every single time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at your pictures, in the picture up top the error mentions 'Tablix1' is invalid.  The 2nd Screenshot, the name of the Tablix is 'Tablix2'.  Try changing the name back to 'Tablix1', or using the Properties section see if you can select Tablix1 in the drop down, and possibly delete it.

Comment: Pay Day row is actually a small table, i forgot to set the data set name for it thats why i was getting the error. Cheers

Answer (score 26):

Just right click on your table => tablix properties=> and set dataset name you want from dropdown and then execute.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty tablix in your report that is not associated with a data set. This will throw that error. Delete any tablix that does not contain data.